# com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException in xamarin.androidx.lifecycle.common/2.6.1

Tags: xamarin.android, .net-6.0

I want to migrate my Xamarin.Android native ptoject to .NET6 and I got this error:

```
Xamarin.Android.D8.targets(79, 5): java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: ../.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.lifecycle.common/2.6.1/buildTransitive/net6.0-android31.0/../../jar/androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common.jar : androidx/lifecycle/DispatchQueue.class
```

I can't understand how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue that many people report it on the GitHub. Someone has found some methods to fix the issue:

For anyone in the future who may have this, I had this issue when my project refers to two library projects each has their own Play Service. This is VS build issue.

Clean the whole solution, then restart VS (this is important). If you still have the problem, you should try closing VS then delete all bin and obj folders then run a dotnet restore before starting VS and build again.

There is a opening issue about [Upgrading Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle packages to version 2.6.1 makes the build fail for duplicated classes](https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/issues/717). You can follow it up for more information.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: It is an open issue on GitHub, and it has not been solved yet. The Xamarin developer will keep following it up. You can check the link I provide to get more information.

Answer (score 1):

My case was a little different.  I received the error after targeting gms.ads.lite versions > 121.4.0.1.  Taking the steps from Guangya Bai, didn't fix the problem for me.  I tried downgrading back to 121.4.0.1, but then the problem changed to an error related to AndroidManifest and Xamarin.Build.Download failed.  Taking the steps from Guangya Bai after the downgrade corrected the problem.  Visual Studio has the odd quirks every now and again that are completely maddening.  Thank you for the post, it helped.